# Restrict access to other schemas

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a user within Oracle Enterprise Manager, this user is the Admin of one schema. How do I restict access to other schemas in bulk, the database has about 50 schemas and the user shouldn't be able to view or interact with these other schemas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is not able by default, unless access to other schemas' objects has been explicitly granted to `PUBLIC`. In this case, you have no easy options to restrict access to them.

Comment: Thank you, the specification states that he shouldn't be able to access other areas but if the database has been designed this way it is out of my reach. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following views to query for the privileges allowed for your user

FOR EXAMPLE: SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS; --USER ALLOWED TABLE

USER_ROLE_PRIVS
USER_SYS_PRIVS
USER_TAB_PRIVS
USER_TAB_PRIVS_MADE
USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD
ALL_COL_PRIVS
ALL_COL_PRIVS_MADE
ALL_COL_PRIVS_RECD
ALL_REPGROUP_PRIVILEGES
ALL_TAB_PRIVS
ALL_TAB_PRIVS_MADE
ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD
USER_AQ_AGENT_PRIVS
USER_COL_PRIVS
USER_COL_PRIVS_MADE
USER_COL_PRIVS_RECD
USER_REPGROUP_PRIVILEGES